# why the `img right` collapse?

Tags: css, css-float

[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/pg7v4js3/)

```
<div class="content clearfix">
    <div class="left">img Left</div>
    <div class="center">Text Center</div>
    <div class="right">img Right</div>
</div>
```

---

`.content {
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        border:1px solid #333;
    }
    .center {
       width: 400px;
       margin:0 auto;
       text-align: center;
    }
    .left {
        float: left;
    }
    .right {
        float: right;
    }` 
I used `float` to layout the page. the left and the center `element` perform well. But the `img Right` was broken. I can't find the reason and what's more I used `line-hegiht`, the collapse is worse. Thanks for your advantage.

Comment: are you want like? this http://jsfiddle.net/kud0kmfa/

Comment: @Kishan horizontal is perfect, but when you add a attribute on the class `content` used `line-height:80px`. The problem is still here.

Comment: floats work as expected when placed _before_ the non-floated elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.center` element is not floated and is centered. If you inspect it, you see its horizontal margins going on left and right (`margin : 0 auto;`).

For the `.left` element, it's ok, it comes before the `.center` element and it is out of the float, so the `.center` element just ignore it.
But the `.right` element comes after, and it has to consider the previous HTML element (here : `.center`). That's why .right element is going under .center element.

So, some solutions :

- you can use absolute positioning for the .right element : `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;` (there : http://jsfiddle.net/pg7v4js3/2/ )
- other solutions depend on what is the real layout you try to achieve

Comment: Thanks a lot. I mainly want to understand the float how to influence the page flow.`position:absolute` is well, but it out of the page flow. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Well, float:left and float: right; make also your elements out of the page flow :)

Comment: you are right. But there is a tiny different specially on Element `img`.If a image has `position:absolute` it will no with, no height in the page flow, but a image has `float:left` or `float:right` it will have height, no width. That's why I don't use `position:absolute`

Comment: Feel free to give an image display:block; if you need it :)

Comment: But well, even with an image, it works as supposed : http://jsfiddle.net/pg7v4js3/2/

Answer (score 1):

This is a new fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pg7v4js3/4/)

```
.clearfix:after{
}
.content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    border:1px solid #333;
}

.center{width: 80%; float: left; text-align: center;}
.left{float: left; width:10%;}
.right{float: right; width:10%;}
```